# knitr Markdown LateX like table within HTML document

Tags: html, r, knitr, r-markdown

I would like to produce "LaTeX-like" table within an HTM document using `knitr` markdown (`.Rmd`) through:

```
knitr::knit2html(input="D:/...Rmd", output="D:/...report.html")
```

Here is an example. However, if I decided to produce a report, the LaTeX table would be incorrect:

```
library(xtable)

xtabl <- xtable(head(CO2))
print(xtabl, type="latex", include.rownames=FALSE)
```

The above gives:

[image]

As suggested here is the result. It was NOT a "LaTeX-like" table!

```
xtabl <- xtable(head(CO2))
print.xtable(xtabl, type="html", include.rownames=FALSE)
```

[image]

**EDIT:**

What I mean by "LaTeX-like" table is this:

[image]

Comment: Hava a look at https://www.rstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/rmarkdown-cheatsheet-2.0.pdf, or please let us know what the problem (and your question) is precisely

Comment: Try removing the `type="latex"` argument, or change to `type="html"` when your desired output is HTML.

Comment: yes, I have tried both, "latex" and "html" non of them gives good result.

Comment: so what is your desired result? what does the wrong result look like?

Comment: with prints-screen of the html provided...

Comment: Try another package, such as ztable, which is very similar to xtable, or stargazer.

Comment: The error message indicates that the print command produced tex code instead of html. Try to replace `print(...)` with `print.xtable(...)`, and of course keep `type="html"`.

Comment: Also packages Gmisc and htmlTable: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/htmlTable/vignettes/tables.html

Comment: @P.Merkle The output of `xtable` has class `xtable`, and it is useless to do `print.xtable` (doing `print(x)` when `x` has class `xtable` is equivalent to do `print.xtable(x)`).

Comment: I think `kable` will do the job

Comment: It's unfortunate this question was not answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example of a basic table with `htmlTable`:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "Author"
date: "2/5/2017"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
```

```{r}
library(htmlTable)
```

```{r, results="asis"}
tab = cbind.data.frame(
  sapply(iris[1:5 , sapply(iris, is.numeric)], function(x) sprintf("%1.1f", x)),
  Species=iris$Species[1:5]
  )

htmlTable(tab, rnames=FALSE, align="rrrrr", align.header="rrrrr",
          css.cell = c(rep("padding-left: 5em", 4), "padding-left: 2em"))
```
````

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is good enough. Although, I was really refering to LaTeX type setting etc.

Answer (score 1):

The [R Markdown cheat sheet](https://www.rstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/rmarkdown-cheatsheet-2.0.pdf) provides a visual comparison of libraries kable, xtable and stargazer. [Stargazer](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/stargazer/index.html) could be what you are looking for.

Also have a look into the [htmlTable](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/htmlTable/vignettes/tables.html) package.

Further customizations could be made with a custom CSS file.

Answer (score 0):

I have used `knitr::kable` for producing the desired tables.

```
mydata <- data.frame(SrNo=c(1,2,3,4), websites=c("stackoverflow", "twitter", "facebook", "google"))
knitr::kable(mydata)
```

`kable` function accepts a `format` argument with possible values `latex`, `html`, etc. see the documentation for details

Complete Markdown file

````
---
title: "kable"
author: "Imran Ali"
date: "February 6, 2017"
output: pdf_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

```{r, echo=FALSE}
mydata <- data.frame(SrNo=c(1,2,3,4), websites=c("stackoverflow", "twitter", "facebook", "google"))
knitr::kable(mydata)
```
````